# Counterexample to Bolzano-Weierstrass in infinite dimension

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

From Bolzano-Weirerstrass we can demonstrate that in a normed vector space $E$ of finite dimension, every bounded sequence admits a limit point.

What are some counterexamples in infinite dimension? **Does there exist a counterexample in every infinite dimensional normed space?**

I believe this one works: Let $E$ be the space of sequences of real numbers with finite support, equipped with the norm $\| (a_k)_{k \in  \mathbb{N} } \|=\sup |a_k|$. Then take define the sequence $(s_n)$ as follows: $s_n$ is the sequence whose $n$th term is $1$ and every other term is $0$. Then $(s_n)$ is bounded, and we can easily show that it has no limit point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**. A normed vector space satisfies the Bolzano-Weierstrass property (i.e. any bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence) if and only if it is of finite dimension. This means there is a counterexample in any infinite dimensional normed vector space.

I only found the [german Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kompaktheitssatz_von_Riesz) for this result (Riesz's compactness theorem), but it uses [Riesz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma) to proof it. I think the proof of the relevant direction might work something like this:

*Proof*.

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed vector space.

Choose some $s_0\in X$ with $\|s_0\|=1$. For any $i\in \Bbb N$ we can define $U_i:=\mathrm{span}(s_0,...,s_{i-1})\subseteq X$ as a closed proper subspace. By the lemma of Riesz there exists $s_{i}\in X- U_i$ with $\|s_i\|=1$ and

$$d(s_{i},U_i):=\inf_{s\in U_i}\|s-s_{i}\|\ge 1/2.$$

The so built sequence is bounded, but no subsequence can be Cauchy, hence not convergent. $\square$

Comment: I think that in your proof you might want to specify that $\|s_i\|=1$ (which is possible by Riesz' lemma) to ensure that the sequence $(s_i)$ is bounded?

Comment: @nobody You are right. Hopefully I fixed it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $X=L^2[0,2\pi]$ and $E=\{\sin nx:n\in\mathbb N\}$.

$E$ does not have a limit point in $X$. Assume otherwise that there is a subsequence
$$\sin {n_k}x\to f(x)\in L^2[0,2\pi].$$
Then we would have that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} (\sin n_kx)^2\,dx- \int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\,\sin n_kx\,dx\to 0.
$$
But $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\,\sin n_kx\,dx\to 0$, while $\int_0^{2\pi} (\sin n_kx)^2\,dx=\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the obvious counter example. You don't need to require finite support, when using supremum norm you only need the sequences to be bounded. Let the $j$th sequence be $k\to \delta_{jk}$ where $\delta_{jk}$ is the  Kronecker delta. Every element in the sequence has norm $1$ and the distance between any two elements is $1$ so clearly this is a bounded sequence that and no subsequence is Cauchy and therefore not convergent.

Comment: Right, this is the example I proposed.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou Yes, obviously it was the obvious counter example;) I didn't read through and came up with the same example...

Comment: Is any case, the bolded question is more interesting I think.